# How to add NestJS to existing Angular Project without two seperated node_modules?

Tags: angular, nestjs

I have a Angular project which is getting data from Google Firestore.
All clear and working.

Now I want to switch from Firestore to own MySQL database, with NestJS and TypeORM.
When adding a subfolder, for example "server", creating a new Nest project with Nest CLI within, it's working too, but I got two node_modules folders, one for the Angular project and one for the Nest project under "server".

How can I use one node_modules folder for both?

The most examples I found are either for a Angular project or a Nest project standalone, a few have both projects but I don't get the magic behind them.

Can someone give me a hint please?

Thanks in advance,
Robert

Comment: Not sure why you need two separate folders for node modules, they are two different applications with different dependencies. Although if they share some of them I've previously used [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/) for something similar.

Comment: You are right, most of the packages are different, but same of course are the same.
Would it be technically correct to have two node_modules folders?

Comment: I would think so. If they share a considerable amount of dependencies, or you will add more packages that have node_modules I would investigate yarn workspaces or something similar. I did not use Nest before so not sure of your specific setup needs :)

Comment: I've read about yarn's workspaces, but I'm using npm all the time and want to avoid introducing a second package manager...
But if it's ok to have two modules folders, then my question is answered.
Thank you!

Comment: If you ever feel the need you can have a look at [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna), this works with npm and handles multiple packages.

Comment: Great, didn't know this one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can clone my repo here https://github.com/malik-evans/presentable.

I'm a nest/angular fan so I've been working at it for a while.  After running. Npm install, run the serve:dev script in the package.json. give angular a while to compile before expecting the ui to load.

Comment: Malik, it would be great if you could share your thoughts on achieving it in the NX workspace. I want to share models between Angular & NestJS project.